# How accurate is Maxminds GeoIP2 compared to GeoLite2 at the first tuesday of the month exactly?

Tags: geoip, maxmind

I would like to know how much the database GeoIP2 is more accurate then the GeoLite2 database, when both databases are downloaded at the first tuesday of the month.

Are there just some ip ranges omitted to get a less accurate dataset?

Answer (score 8):

MaxMind publishes accuracy figures for the GeoLite2 and GeoIP2 databases. See the [accuracy page](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-city-database-accuracy) and select a country for comparison data. GeoIP2 databases are more accurate than GeoLite2 databases, because the former is built using more data.

Comment: But that's the City accuracy, how to get the Country accuracy?

Comment: Seems that link has changed because it shows country accuracy now, not city. Also, it doesn't seem to differentiate between GeoLite2 and GeoIP2

Answer (score 3):

GeoIP2 is 99.8% accurate on a country level.
GeoLite2 should be about the same on a country level, but MaxMind does not confirm this.